# Catchs more events into the iframe diagrams.net

Tags: draw.io, diagrams.net

I would like to know if in app.diagram.net (embedded) it was possible to capture events via postMessage() from the app to the client and vice versa?

Here is what I am looking for:

- the "drag and drop" event of a shape on the canvas
- the right click on an element

Or the setting in the librairies of upstream elements in the iframe config to handle postMessage()

I thank you in advance,
Have a nice evening.

Comment: Only if the embedded page is set up to emit such events.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 

In this direction: Parent -> Iframe I do well "what I want" as event.
It's in the opposite direction: Iframe -> Parent that I would like to have the information of adding an element on the canvas.

Either by a "custom shape" which has events developed upstream, or by events generated by the library in the iframe directly which sends the information (like the "init" for example)